# What look and feel component do I set to change the text color of a TitledBorder?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I have a group of radio buttons in my Swing application that have a border built around them as follows:

```
radioButtonPanel.setBorder( new CompoundBorder ( 
    BorderFactory.createTitledBorder( " Input Data " ), padBorder ) );
```

Our application supports two look and feels, a light and a dark one. When switching between the two, the border color itself appears to change colors correctly, but the text does not.  For the life of me, I can't figure out what the name of the component is I should be setting the color of.  The documentation for `createTitledBorder()` says it uses the default look and feel, but I'm unsure where it's pulling its default.  I thought it was the `Panel.foreground`, but that's not it and nothing else seems to look quite right.

Does anybody know which look and feel component I need to be setting here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the title colour on a TitledBorder instance or create one using a constructor that takes the title colour as an argument.

The [TitledBorder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/border/TitledBorder.html) javadoc also states that "TitledBorder.titleColor" property from the look and feel is used as the default. You can override this as follows:

```
UIManager.getDefaults().set("TitledBorder.titleColor", Color.RED);
```

Comment: Yep, that's definitely the one. A little annoyed I didn't find that on my own, but absolutely appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling

```
UIManager.getDefaults().set("TitledBorder.titleColor", Color.RED);
```

you will need to call

```
UIManager.put("TitledBorder.titleColor", Color.RED);
```